# The use for asynchronous programming (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

I don't have a specific problem but I'd like to have the opinion from others about my own doubts. I'm not an advanced developer so if what I say is stupid or completely wrong, do not hesitate to correct me and bear with me, I'm here to learn.

I've been using NodeJS a lot recently, and of course, most of my code is written in an asynchronous fashion. However, I've come to think about several things:

It is harder for me to write readable code, with a flow easy to reason about, when I wrote asynchronous code rather than synchronous. I also often end up with a lot of nested callbacks. Later, I learned about promises and I think it improves the whole thing but even with promises, I feel like the code I write is still hard to maintain and error-prone.

I also realized that a lot of the time, I'd rather do synchronous calls but I'm more or less forced to use asynchronous calls because libraries only provide asynchronous interfaces. For instance, very often, I need to get data from a database and will end up writing asynchronous code for querying the database, or in another situation I need make a request to a server (e.g. to get a token to use a third party service), but in all these situations, I need to get the data (be it data from a db or a token or whatever) before sending my own response, so I need to wait. But I end up forced to write asynchronous code while I feel like synchronous code would be more natural and more readable.

I know that with NodeJS I shouldn't block the main thread with synchronous calls, so it seems like asynchronous programming is the only way to go. But I would like to know whether I should just drop NodeJS and go for something else that would allow me to write synchronous code, or if there is something that I have missed about NodeJS.

Comment: I/O is pretty much always asynchronous. Even if you can do it synchronously, it won't scale. Imagine a web browser was single threaded and would do synchronous I/O. I wouldn't be able to use the browser while I downloading a file (not even talking about how slow and unresponsive loading a website would be). What to do depends entirely on what you are building. But getting used to and learning asynchronous programming will certainly be more beneficial.

Comment: @Mat could you please show some of your code that you have difficulties to read?

Answer (score 1):

Choosing your language or framework will be based on your use case. Preference will come after. It's true that most of the times, a more synchronous oriented language is much easier to maintain and read (I'm looking at you Python). But take this for example:

- You need to do something that requires completion of multiple tasks, and you want the result sooner. Surely, doing this in a synchronous manner will slow you down. Best thing is to write the code in a language or framework that has built in concurrency: NodeJS, Erlang, Go
- You need to write a script that should go over resources in a sequential manner. While this can be done in the languages stated on my previous scenario, it's probably best for you to resort into a language or framework that does this more easily: Python, Ruby, Perl

In my opinion, it's good to learn NodeJS. Remember that you shouldn't be stuck to one language for your whole life.

Answer (score 1):

Promises will fix your readability problem.

```
doAsync(data, function(err, result){
    doAnotherAync(result, function(err, newResult){
        console.log(newResult);
    })
});
```

becomes

```
doPromise(data)
    .then(function(result){
        return doAnotherPromise(result)
    })
    .then(function(newResult){
        console.log(newResult);
    });
```

Promises are now part of ES6. As a warning: they are not immediately "obvious". Code up a few examples until the penny drops. You'll be glad you did. Also use [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/).

Don't give up on Node. It truly is a thing of beauty.

Answer (score 1):

To solve problems in an asynchronous world requires asynchronous programs. And our internetworked world is decidedly asynchronous. You simply cannot write a program that involves waiting for something in synchronous fashion. It is not up to you whether to write a synchronous or asynchronous program; the problem decides this for you.

The best you can do is to find languages and frameworks that make it easier. In JS, asynchronous functions with `await` are the advance that allows you to write asynchronous programs in a style as close as humanly possibly to synchronous.

Comment: If it's an asynchronous world, why only now does asynchronous programming seem to have exploded onto the scene?

Comment: @Jodes Asynchronous programming has been here ever since `setTimeout` arrived in Netscape 2, and then XMLHTTPRequest/ajax more than 15 years ago. What has changed, not "only now", but more like starting five years ago--is that we have improved paradigms in JS for dealing with it, such as promises, async functions, and observables.